# Any way to join these two queries without subquery?

Tags: mysql

I have this query: **It gets the list of friends of a specific user**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(friend_id) AS friends
FROM friends_friends 
WHERE user_id = 503695576;
```

Which gives me a comma delimited list of that particular users friends.

Then using that query I have this query: **It gets the list of the users friends, friends**

```
SELECT friend_id
FROM friends_friends 
WHERE user_id IN(friends);
```

I am not too experienced in joins, etc, but is there anyway I can do a join or something similar to make this one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(l2.friend_id) AS friends
FROM friends_friends l1
  JOIN friends_friends l2
    ON l2.user_id = l1.friend_id
WHERE l1.user_id = 503695576;
```

Comment: This was the solution for me. Thanks!