# Filter out with Join

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(b.friend_id) AS possible_id
FROM friends_friends a
    JOIN friends_friends b 
      ON b.user_id = a.friend_id
WHERE a.user_id = 123456789
```

Essentially what it does is it get a list of possible friends by getting the users friends friends

Now what I want to do is **filter out the list of that particular users friends**

Here is an example to get that users friends

```
SELECT friend_id
FROM friends_friends
WHERE user_id = 123456789
```

I want to achieve this using a Join, I know its simple but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to join these two queries without subquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409582/any-way-to-join-these-two-queries-without-subquery)

Comment: This is not a duplicate but rather a different situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(b.friend_id) AS possible_id
FROM friends_friends a
    JOIN friends_friends b 
      ON b.user_id = a.friend_id
    LEFT JOIN friends_friends c
      ON c.user_id = a.user_id
     AND b.family_id = c.friend_id
WHERE a.user_id = 123456789
AND c.friend_id IS NULL
```

This worked for me :)

Comment: Do you have a `family_id` in your table? :o

Comment: hah.. forgot to change that. I changed it to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a NOT IN clause to your where clause:

```
and b.friend_id NOT IN (SELECT friend_id
FROM friends_friends
WHERE user_id = 123456789)
```

Comment: While tempting, and intuitively sound, queries with `NOT IN` sometimes yield bad performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(b.friend_id) AS possible_id
FROM friends_friends a
     JOIN friends_friends b 
       ON b.user_id = a.friend_id
LEFT JOIN friends_friends n
       ON b.user_id = n.friend_id AND n.user_id = 123456789 
WHERE a.user_id = 123456789 AND n.friend_id IS NULL
```

I think I got that right...